# Paypal IPN Script / MySql Insert Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, paypal

I'm having an issue with my IPN script.
Its fine for verifying payment etc but im trying to get it to input the data into a database.
The user email and password entry prior to works fine but not the second one..

```
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

$email = $_POST['item_name'];
$password = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$Random = print_r($_POST);


mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES('". mysql_escape_string($email)     ."', '".md5($password)."') ") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO LNCH_Sales SET
                                                            item_name = '%s',
                                                            item_number = '%s',
                                                            payment_status = '%s',
                                                            payment_amount = '%s',
                                                            payment_currency = '%s',
                                                                txn_id = '%s',
                                                            receiver_email = '%s',
                                                            payer_email = '%s'",
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($item['name']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($item['number']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($payment['status']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($payment['amount']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($payment['currency']),       
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($txn['id']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($receiver['email']),
                                                            mysql_real_escape_string($payer['email'])

                                                                      );
```

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Your Syntax is wrong - instead of

```
INSERT INTO LNCH_SALES SET
```

(which looks like a mixture between INSERT and UPDATE), you need

```
INSERT INTO LNCH_SALES(<column_list>) VALUES (...
```

Answer (score 0):

as @FrankSchmitt said problably your are missing the column list.

the only way that you can skip the columns list is if the number of insert columns = to the number of the table columns, I.E:

```
jcho360> create table test (id int,name varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

jcho360> insert into test values (1,'Jcho360');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

jcho360> insert into test values (1);
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

jcho360> insert into test(id) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

As you can see only if I goning to fill all the columns in an "insert" you can skip the columns list.